# How to validate non-db attributes on an ActiveRecord model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have the following class:

```
class Instance < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :resolution
  validates_format_of :resolution, with: /\A\d+x{1}\d+\d/

  def resolution=(res)
    validate!
    (set the resolution etc)
  end

  def resolution
    (get the resolution and return)
  end
end
```

The resolution attribute is not stored in the database, but is a transient property of the instance.

When it calls validate!, validation fails no matter what what rule is included. Without it, validation doesn't work at all.

How can I validate properly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate non-model field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062715/validate-non-model-field)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validation of virtual attributes in Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748941/validation-of-virtual-attributes-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `=~` operator instead to match a string with regex, using this you can add a condition in setter methods

```
def resolution=(res)
  if res =~ /\A\d+x{1}\d+\d/
    # do something
  else
    # errors.add(...)
  end
end
```

**but**, as you have already used `attr_accessor`, you don't have to define getter and setter explicitly, the role of `attr_accessor` is to define getter and setter methods only, you can do this instead

```
class Instance < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :resolution
  validates_format_of :resolution, with: /\A\d+x{1}\d+\d/
end
```

The above solution will work perfectly!

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks! Can I combine both methods? (i.e. have attr_accessor and defined setters/getters)

Comment: Yes of course, you can override the default methods!

Answer (score 1):

The `validate!` method should be called after setting the variable. In the given example you call `validate!` when the value is still nil.