# How to make client_side_validations work for a field that is created dynamically using JavaScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation

I am using [client_side_validations](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations) in a Ruby on Rails application form.
I have a select field which is converted to a Jquery combobox on page load.
That means, I do not see the select box on my screen rather I see the combobox.

How to apply the same client side validations of that select field on the combobox ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I am not used to comboboxes but if it replaces a select then you don't really need a validation on a select. All data is prefilled. What do you want to validate exactly ?

Comment: In a new form,  combo box remains blank initially and allows user to either enter an input by typing just like a text field or select a value from attached drop down to it. Here is an example of combo box: http://jsfiddle.net/alforno/PThuq/show

Comment: Basically it still behaves like a select. So the user has little room for a different input that the one expected. You can validate the different values in your model but basically you want to enforce the presence ? Does it not work with client side validations ? In my case I had a problem with radio button for gender, I have defaulted to one of the two genders because the presence was not enforced through client side validations.. not sure about select...

Comment: @Maxence I can enforce a default value to combobox but it behaves like a text box also. That means any user can clear the default value from the field and go to the next field. And there wont be any client side validation to warn user.

Comment: But exactly what do you want to validate in your combobox ? that the user picks a value from the drop down only? If you make your select a combobox then you are ok that the user types a different value than the ones offered ? What validation do you need to perform on this new value ?

Comment: I just want to validate presence on the combo box using the plugin.

Comment: then `validates :comboboxfield, presence: true` does not work ?

Comment: @Maxence combobox is created on the fly by JQuery. I tried adding `attr_accessor :comboboxfield, presence: true` to  model and added `name=comboboxfield` to combobox input field. Still it does not work!

Comment: If your field that you are adding in your form is an `attr_accessor` I recommend you read threads about validating `attr_accessor`like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062715/validate-non-model-field